# How to create a kind of variable Checkbox in vba excel

Tags: vba, checkbox

I have the next excel sheet with many checkboxs.

[image]

The problem is when I am coding I have to do some functions with **Valor1** and **Valor2** depending of if the **checkbox** is activate.

Well I have the code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Casilladeverificación1_Haga_clic_en()

    Range("c12").Activate

    Do


        If CheckBox1.Value Then
            Call fucntion1
        'Works for the first row, but for the second row int shoul be check CheckBox12 ,a next CheckBox23 ...

        If CheckBox2.Value Then
            Call fucntion1

        If CheckBox2.Value Then
            Call fucntion3

        ....

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

    While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value2)

End Sub
```

But you can notice I dont want to made all the case with all the **checkbox**, there is a solve for this like **checkbox[i]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put all of your functions into one big function and the functionality would separated by a `Select Case` block.

```
 Private Sub functionRouter(checkAction as integer)
 Select Case checkAction
      Case 1
         'Code for function one
      Case 2
         'Code for function two
      ''Etc.
 End Select
 End Sub
```

You're going to want to loop over all your check boxes. This is going to depend on what checkbox you are using.

```
 Sub test()

 Dim chkBox As CheckBox
 Dim chkBox2 As OLEObject

 'Regular
 For Each chkBox In Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBoxes
  Debug.Print chkBox.Caption
 Next chkBox

 'ActiveX
 For Each chkBox2 In Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects
  If TypeName(chkBox2.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
     Debug.Print chkBox2.Object.Value
  End If
 Next chkBox2
```

You could do a few different things with all of your checkboxes. You could use the `tag`property (you would need to set all of them, but this allows for duplicates). Then call `functionRouter(chkBox.tag)` Or you could parse something from the name `functionRouter Right(chkBox.name, 1)`

Comment: Thats awsome, but Im testing now, I have some question about the differences between CheckBox and OLEObject, but I am using OLEObject, please try to follow that post, for you I am going to have more questions.

Comment: Ok so you're going to be using `chkBox2.object.Value` and `.Name` or `.Tag` I tried to look in the object browser for a way to reference it directly but I haven't found it yet. Make sure you always use `.Object` before you try to get to one of its properties. Honestly I don't know the major differences between the two. One is native to Excel. Probably for legacy support the ActiveX is the newer version and is likely more powerful (but harder to use)

Comment: Hey I tryed with chkBox2.Object.Tag but I have **the object does not support this property or method** but I am doing to parse the numbers of the `.name` and  if divide by 11 and working with this value.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate checkboxes on worksheet by using this loop:

```
For Each chk In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    MsgBox chk.Name
Next
```

It won't work if you use `ActiveX` controls though.